# Android ListView only scrolls when touching first or second list item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, xamarin

I use a `ListView` in a `SwypeRefreshLayout` and scrolling only works in the upper area of the `View`.
I also tried other layouts like `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` and worked with a `ScrollView`, but it only scrolls on the first two elements of the list.
Whats wrong?

Fragment Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/DeviceOverviewRefresher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id="@+id/DeviceOverviewList" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

ListRowLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Text"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/DeviceName" />
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thx for your help!

Comment: Try to set `clickable` and `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` to your item layout to `false`. Although - have you set `OnClickListener` to children instead of `OnListItemClick`?

Comment: What do you mean by scrolling? Scrolling inside items or scrolling to PTR? Scrolling the whole ListView, up or down? Is your device's touch hardware ok? You could turn on touch displaying in developers options to see if device catches your gestures and touches in bottom part of the screen.

Comment: I meant that scolling the whole list is only possible, if my finger is on the first or second item of the list. If I try scrolling in the middle of the screen it doesn't start to move.

@Petrov Dmitrii: I'll try that now.

Comment: @Stan: I tried it on multiple devices like Nexus 5, Galaxy S5 Neo... the touch event was caught on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Weird, but removing one line of code solved it.
I just removed the animation in my "ShowFragment" - Method.

```
var trans = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
// animation
//trans.SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.slide_down, Resource.Animation.slide_up);
```